# Error 1004 Initializing a UserForm object?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I can't figure out why this line is throwing the "Error 1004: Application Defined or Object Defined error"? Can someone help?

The object "CombQTY" is a combo box in a userform "MASTER". I am trying to populate the drop down menu of this combo box with the range "QTY_range" (size is 31 rows of numbers in a column = 0,1,2,3,..30).

I have tried swapping the "Userform" with "MASTER" and vice versa.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

MASTER.CombQTY.List = Worksheets("RANGES").Range("QTY_range").Value

End Sub
```

I can't understand why its throwing that error because I don't see any problem with this code. Please help

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when asking your question. Text in ALL CAPS is difficult to read and understand, and it's somewhat rude to SHOUT for attention. Thanks.

Comment: Is the named range definitely on that sheet? Your code works for me.

Comment: What are the dimensions of QTY_Range ?

Comment: Never refer to a form's default instance in that form's code-behind. If `CombQTY` is a control on that userform, the only correct qualifier to use is `Me`. Otherwise you are assigning the `List` property of the `CombQTY` combobox *on the default instance* of the form, ....which may or may not be *that* instance. Unqualified `Worksheets` is implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is; a proper `Workbook` object qualifier would be needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering your question, but relative to what you're doing (we don't see what `QTE_range` address is).

---

I tend to loop and collect a list, so i don't have to worry about the dimensions of my named range (more columns than rows).. .example code (untested):

```
dim i as range, a as range, arr as variant
set a = thisworkbook.names("QTE_range").referstorange
for each i in a
    if arr(ubound(arr)) <> "" then redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1)
    arr(ubound(arr)) = i.value
next 
Me.CombQTY.List = arr
```

Note the references... userform is `Me` and workbook is `thisworkbook`, which could be antoher ref, or to a sheet name, etc.

Comment: Postscript:  i also changed how to reference your named range, whcih doesn't require the sheet name (in case you have it wrong)... `Names().RefersToRange`

Comment: Upvoted - only needs some error handling to avoid blowing up with a type mismatch when `arr(ubound(arr))` contains a worksheet error and that error value is being compared to `""`, but that wasn't in scope.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Very true.  I think the only truly in scope thing I could add would be the single line code that reads:  `Me.CombQTY.List = ThisWorkbook.Names("QTE_range").RefersToRange.Value`