# Populate a ComboBox on a userform from range

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have created a userform with cascading **ComboBoxes**, and the values for the two ComboBoxes are taken from two columns in a worksheet. 
The code works fine, but when I try to create the same userform with slightly different data, I can't seem to make the ComboBoxes work - they just come up empty.

I've tried using a specific range instead of `D2` & `LastRow` but I can't get it to work.

```
Private Sub Seven_Initialize()

ComboBox_Area.List = Sheets("Seven").Range("E2:E18").Value

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox_Area_Change()

Dim rngZone As Range
Dim rngList As Range
Dim strSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long

      If ComboBox_Area.ListIndex <> -1 Then

           strSelected = ComboBox_Area.Value

           LastRow = Worksheets("Seven").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

           Set rngList = Worksheets("Seven").Range("D2" & LastRow)

           For Each rngZone In rngList

                 If rngZone.Value = strSelected Then

                      ComboBox_Seven.AddItem rngZone.Offset(, -1)

                 End If

           Next rngZone

      End If

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as it works perfectly fine in a different userform with very similar data.

Comment: The initialize event name is "hard-wired". It should be `Private Sub Userform_Initialize()`.

Comment: Thanks SJR! This fixed the first part of the issue, but the second ComboBox still comes up empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.Value` to the combobox_seven `rngZone.Offset(, -1).Value`?

Comment: Yes - unfortunately still doesn't work...

Comment: Refer to the workbook as well. It may be that it's looking at the active workbook

Comment: It should be: `Range("D2:D" & LastRow)`

Comment: `LastRow = Worksheets("Seven").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`  Should read `LastRow = Worksheets("Seven").Range("D" & Worksheets("Seven").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`... need that worksheet qualification on the rows.count

Comment: I posted soemthing yesterday which may be of help to you.  Use an array to store your values, then set the combobox.list equal to that array... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837162/3233363

Comment: Thank you all! Rory - your solution worked perfectly!